# How to use front tablet's webcam with HTML GetUserMedia?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webcam-capture, webcam.js

I am trying to use [WebcamJS](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) in Chrome on Windows tablet which has 2 webcams. However, it is working only with back webcam.

Any idea how to make it work with front webcam ?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fork of that project that allows that very feature (the ability to choose the camera device): https://github.com/carvilsi/webcamjs

Hope this helps.