# Access mobile device Rear(Back) Camera from javascript using getusermedia

Tags: javascript

I am using webcam.js by https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs and in mobile devices, the front camera is opening by default. I want to change the default to the rear camera.

Is there any way to change the camera device?

Comment: Since this is a pretty specific question, maybe open an issue on the GitHub page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use front tablet's webcam with HTML GetUserMedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485544/how-to-use-front-tablets-webcam-with-html-getusermedia)